# Unable to get refresh token of https://management.azure.com/ using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token, refresh-token

I am trying to get Access token and refresh token for the "https://management.azure.com/" resource using PowerShell, but I am getting an only Access token. I need a refresh token as well. I share my code as below.

```
$clientID = '1xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
$secretKey = 'kdfudifkldfliKASDFKkdfjd-ddkjfidysikd'
$tenantID = 'fxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secretKey -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ClientID,$password)
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant $tenantID

$authUrl = "https://login.windows.net/" + $tenantID + "/oauth2/token/"
$body = @{
   "resource" = "https://management.azure.com/";
   "grant_type" = "client_credentials";
   "client_id" = $ClientID
   "client_secret" = $secretKey
}

Write-Output "Getting Authentication-Token ..." 
$adlsToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $authUrl –Method POST -Body $body
Write-Output $adlsToken
```

**------------output---------------**

```
Getting Authentication-Token ...
token_type     : Bearer
expires_in     : 3599
ext_expires_in : 3599
expires_on     : 1597999269
not_before     : 1597995369
resource       : https://management.azure.com/
access_token   : J0uYFoioURT4CdISuUrRrr...
```

[image]

Comment: In your case, the correct way is to run your script again to get the new access token instead of using the refresh token to get a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec states the **Client Credentials** grant type MUST NOT allow for the issuing of refresh tokens. So the answer is, you have to use a different grant type to receive a refresh token with your access token.

Therefore, it is recommended that you use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), which will return the **refresh token** to you when you request the token.

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: then, what should be the grant type for this?

Comment: I guess body parameters are wrong to make a request. Can you please suggest the correct parameters? @Carl Zhao!

Comment: @Ashish-BeJovial  First you need to request the "code" in the browser according to the document, and then use the "code" to request the token.

Comment: is this code generated from somewhere or I can paste anything as value of code?

Comment: This code is unique, it needs you to obtain it in the browser according to your request parameters,  there is a detailed explanation in the document I provided.

Comment: You can make a reference based on this example first:  https://swimlane.com/blog/microsoft-oauth2-implementation-3/

Comment: @Ashish-BeJovial  Hi, Give me some time and I will write a example for you based on your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this effort @Carl, it will be a great help.

Comment: Hi @Carl, have you got chance to have a look on  this?

Comment: @Ashish-BeJovial  Hi, Sorry for my late reply, I found a similar one, please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200571/can-i-use-mfa-app-passwords-with-azure-oauth2-0-ropc

Comment: @Ashish-BeJovial Have you got solution for this?

Comment: yes, But I have changed the way to get an access tokens. At the time of installation of my desktop app. I copied the powershell script in appdata folder, and as my application run that powershell will be execute save an access token in Azure Blob, from blob I am able to continue to use that token. I hope this will help you.